# Parameter specification in entity framework lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

Is there a different between the two statements below, perhaps in terms of performance or readability, assuming you have a model named RateCountry with CountryCode as one of the properties. Of course in my project I will only have one return statement

```
public RateCountry GetRateCountry(string countryCode, int rateId)
{
    return _directConnectContext.RateCountries.FirstOrDefault(rc => rc.CountryCode == countryCode && rc.RateID == rateId);

    return _directConnectContext.RateCountries.Where(rc => rc.CountryCode == countryCode && rc.RateID == rateId).FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

Comment: EF is an ORM. LINQ queries generate SQL queries in the end. Compare the generated SQL text. I suspect they'll be either identical or equivalent. There's only one way to write `SELECT TOP 1 FROM X where ...` after all

Comment: As long as your are dealing with an `IQueryable` which if `_directConnectContext` is an EF DB context you are, then there is no difference.

Comment: @AshleyMedway wrong source. That's for Enumerable, not Queryable

Comment: @AshleyMedway Queryable's source doesn't matter though, the *generated SQL query* does. That's done by the provider. It's easier to simply check the generated queries

Comment: First statement is simply a shortcut for (a concise version of ) the second, hence performance should be the same. What about readability, it's a matter of personal preference, hence is opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equality of LINQ statements is defined by equality of generated SQL code. If you look at generated SQL code of both queries, you will see that they are the same. So, answering your question - no, there is no difference.